# CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am deploying my MVC app on a windows server 2016 instance.

I deployed my website to IIS on my local machine first and everything worked just fine. I then went to my server, installed the EXACT same database (but it is empty) to my server and then deployed my application via File System.

However, it is giving me the `CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'.  error.`

How do I fix this?
Again, this does not happen when I run it on my local machine with the exact same database name.

Comment: try `use MyDatabase` before creating tables.

Comment: What is that? More info please. where do I write that?

Comment: How did you deploy the production database?  Does your application create tables or execute stored procedures that create tables?  Did you double check the connection string(s) when the application was deployed?

Comment: I used the sql express .exe tool on both my local db and on my production db. The application creates the tables using code first

Comment: I figured it out... but I dont know why....When I went through the create database tutorial I am using windows authentication... Administrator was the only one, and i made it \Everyone and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

So here it is, I almost forgot this question was still opened.

When I deployed my application to `IIS` I had to also install `microsoft SQL` to the server. When installing the `microsoft SQL server` **you are asked about permissions** and which user can access the database.

Well **IIS runs on a different user access level than perhaps "Travis" or "Joe"**. 
I solved this problem by simply chosing **"Everyone"** when setting up `microsoft SQL` this is probably not best practice, but it allowed me to connect to my database and move on to other problems!

Answer (score 0):

I don't now what really fixed my problem, but

I delete next code from web.config

```
<contexts>
    <context type="......, .....">
        <databaseInitializer type="......" />
    </context>
</contexts>
```

set user settings as owner and set my DB as default in sql/logins/Mylogin ->right click - properties.

Comment: hmm. Interesting. Later on I was experimenting with mine and actually found that the permission levels of the MySQL database were actually set to administrator only. So by changing the permission levels of the actual database, my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, what I did I verified my connection string in the app service configuration and I found a small mistake in it, I corrected it and it worked fine for me.

Azure portal >> App service >> Configuration >> Connection Strings